# Codename One: AutoComplete textfield connection with SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, autocomplete, codenameone

I would like to connect an autocomplete text field to an SQLite database. The user should be able to type in a few letters and then select the item they would like to add from possible suggestions. Once the user adds the item (by pressing a button), an SQL query should retrieve other values from the selected item row.

[Example of database table row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kMrU.jpg)

To summarise, I would like the following:

1. An autocomplete component to provide suggested items (ItemName from database) after the user types a few letters
2. Perform an SQL query to retrieve values (Salt and Sugar from database) and keep a running total of salt and sugar. Theses values should then be added to a table containing 2 rows with 2 columns, as follows.

Salt | [value from database + total salt]

Sugar | [value from database + total sugar]

I would therefore appreciate therefore any advice and guidance on how these could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a select query on `ItemName` specifically:

```
select `ItemName` from tablename
```

Then use that data for your auto complete code.

When the action listener for the auto complete fires just issues the query

```
"select * from tablename where ItemName='" + mySelection + "'"
```

Then use the column values in the returned row. You also need to deal with a case of nothing being returned if the user typed in something that isn't available in the list and pressed "Done".